# Geolocation from form

Tags: javascript, database, forms, geolocation, street-address

I have a Javascript form where a user inputs an address, city, and state. When this form is submitted, I want the address to be converted into latitude and longitude, and to store those two values to a database. Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Pekka you are correct using Google map geocoding is only allow for within map, and permits storage only for improve performance of the map. @Fusionice for what purpose are you storing the lat lng for?

Comment: To display a Google map using the stored lat lng values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

http://batchgeo.com/lookup/

Comment: This would be perfect if I knew how to only display the output map on a page

Comment: Grab their map div. It's id="mapDiv". This is slightly ghetto, because if they change this, your stuff stops working. It'd be better if they had an API, but I didn't see one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Maps API v3, example:

```
//get the input from user, in a normal looking address string
var add = this.ListingAddress + ', ' + this.ListingCity + ', ' + this.ListingZipCode;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': add }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var LatLong = results[0].geometry.location; //here is the LatLong
    } else {
        alert("Address not found! Error Code: " + status);
    }
});
```